# Google Reporting API for Analytics library dependencies

Tags: grails, google-analytics-api

I want to retrieve some data from Google Analytics using Reporting API, but I can't figure out the right dependencies for Maven to get it work. My app is in Grails, so I'm using BuildConfig.groovy, but it should be similar for Maven:

```
plugins {
        compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.17.0-rc'
        compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc'
        compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.17.0-rc'
        compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev74-1.17.0-rc"
}
```

The code above throws error Failed to resolve dependencies. What dependencies am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
dependencies {
    build 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analytics:v3-rev74-1.17.0-rc'
}
```